# Filtering Duplicates In A List

Tags: c#, list, hashset

I have a list I want to filter for duplicate items. I searched on StackOverflow before asking this question and found two solutions; using `.Distinct()` and using a `HashSet`, however none of these methods worked for me. The object I am trying to filter implements the `.Equals` method, but it still doesn't work.

I tested this by created 500 objects that are exactly the same and putting them in the list. I expected 1 to be left, but all 500 are still there. Does my object need to implement additional methods for this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some code showing your equals method and how you are using the Distinct

Comment: Regarding Tim Schmelter's answer, can you tell us if the object also overrides GetHashCode? If it doesn't, do you have access to the source code of the object's class?

Comment: It didn't override it, but now it does and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you override `Equals` always also override  `GetHashCode`.

[Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)

Here's a simple class to demonstrate a possible implementation. `GetHashCode` should be efficient and should produce few collisions:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Foo other = obj as Foo;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return this.ID == other.ID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID;
    }
}
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/284240) another implementation if your equality check needs to include multiple properties or a collection:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
    {
        int hash = 17;
        // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
        hash = hash * 23 + field1.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + field2.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + field3.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however I don't understand why you set the value of `hash` multiple times. Won't `hash = hash * 23 + field3.GetHashCode();` override all of the other lines? Shouldn't it be `+=` instead?

Comment: @TheGateKeeper: That's `hash = hash * 23 + ...`, so it's not overwriting it but taking the old old value and adding the next hashcode.